# Is the code available for the MarkLogic Pharma Research Hub example?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I'd like to use the MarkLogic Pharma Research Hub as an example to demonstrate the data hub functionality and end point. Is the code and documentation available anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the [Data Hub Service for Pharma R&D](https://www.marklogic.com/product/data-hub-service/pharma-rd/) lives at:

https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-research-hub-framework

Answer (score 0):

The MarkLogic Data Hub is an open-source software interface that works to ingest data from multiple sources, harmonize that data, master it, and then search and analyze it. It runs on MarkLogic Server, and together, they provide a unified platform for mission-critical use cases.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).